# Using entity metadata wrappers not saving data

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7 and the entity module, I have a contenttype setup called property, what I'm attempting to do is to create content types from a xml file, I have the correct data and I'm using the entity_metadata_wrapper to simplify insertion into the fields:

Here is the method I'm using:

```
private function newProperty($propValues) {
    global $user;
    $values = array(
      'type' => 'property',
      'uid' => $user->uid,
      'status' => 1,
      'comment' => 1,
      'promote' => 0,
    );
    $entity = entity_create('node', $values);
    $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
    $ewrapper->title->value=$propValues->price_text;
    $ewrapper->field_property_expert_agent_ref->value =$this->xml_attribute($propValues, 'reference');

    foreach ($this->valuesToFetch() as $key=>$value) {
        $ewrapper->{$value}->value=$propValues->$key;
    }
    $ewrapper->save();
    entity_save('node', $entity);
}
```

$propValues holds an array of values
$this->valuesToFetch() is a key=>value array eg : 'department'=>'field_property_department',
I have added debugging code to confirm that the values are coming through, the ct gets created but its values are empty.

What am I doing wrong?

https://drupal.org/node/1021556

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set field values using entity_metadata_wrapper you must to use `->set()` method or rely the [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) which can offer more code clarity.

```php
// 1. Using ->set()
// Single value 
$wrapper->field_data->set($value);
// Multi value
$wrapper->field_data[]->set($value); // Add to field array
$wrapper->field_data[$delta]->set($value); // Set specific value

// 2. Using magic methods 
// Single value 
$wrapper->field_data = $value
// Multi value
$wrapper->field_data[] = $value; // Add to field array
$wrapper->field_data[$delta] = $value; // Set specific value

// 3. Deleting values
// 'Unset' a field value (there is no delete method)
$wrapper->field_data->set(NULL);
$wrapper->field_data = NULL;
```

[Drupal 7 Entity metadata wrappers documentation.](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers) 
[A good blog post that has some useful insights!](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/death-field-arrays/)

Comment: Its actually been a while since I posted this, but taking a look at what I eventually did this was the case

Answer (score 1):

Used the set() method as revagomes mentionned or the magic method __set()

```
$wrapper->field_data = $value; // Maaaagic !
```

And it's way more readable this way ;) Go impress your code reviewer :p